# Editing resources in Microsoft Project VBA not reflected on server

Tags: vba, ms-project, ms-project-server-2010

when I try to edit an enterprise resource in Microsoft Project using VBA (SetField method of resource), I am able to set custom fields, and can see those custom field changes with GetField, but these changes are not seen on the server/in PWA. And when I restart MS Project and run the VBA the changes are gone.

Am I missing something? Do I need to add a line of code to check in my changes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem in my C# code. You have to publish your project after the changes:

1. Get ProjectDataSet from the server
2. Do your local changes to the dataset
3. Check out the project
4. Update the DataSet (send it to the server)
5. Check in the project
6. **Publish the project!**

I hope it will help
Florian ([geeklife.ch](http://geeklife.ch/dev/))